# How to restrict flushing of specific objects using before_flush()

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have three tables: fits, character, and skills. Each `Character` has a list of `Skill`s, of which the skill level can be changed. Each `Fit` belongs to a `Character`, and a `Character` may own any number of fits.

I would like the user to be able to change the levels of the skills belonging to a `Character`, but on a temporary basis. That is, when they change it, they can close the program and lose the changes, or choose to save the changes they have done. This seems difficult to do for three reasons:

- Any time the `Character` object changes (which has a list of Skill objects), it is added as a dirty object to the session. This leads into the next problem...
- Any time other things in the program change (the `Fit` object is modified, the user creates new `Character`s, etc), the program does a flush/commit, which would include the temporary changes that were made to previous characters
- I do not wish to `expunge()` the character from the session, because when a new fit is loaded, it will load a new Character object fresh from the database. This is unwanted as I wish to use the modified Character for all fits that are assigned to that characters, and I do not want extra Character objects floating around.

Basically, I want the user to tweak the `Character` object without fear of having it saved with a session flush/commit from another change.

I have thought about using SQLalchemys `before_flush` event, but examples of using it seem to be sparse. I envision setting a property on the Character whenever it is changed, and then checking for this property before flushing.  If it has this property, remove it from the flush pool and flush/commit all other changes. I think this would be exactly what I need, however I'm not sure how to work with the events.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. One possible solution is to create a 'transient' to store the temporary skill. Create a [reconstructor](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/constructors.html#sqlalchemy.orm.reconstructor)

```
def Skill: 
    @orm.reconstructor
    def init_on_load(self):
        self.current_skill = self.skill

    def save_current_skill():
         self.skill = self.curent_skill
```

Don't forget to override the constructot to create the filed